how to change/add gpg key to pass
I need to change the gpg key originally used for pass on my system to a newly generated key.
However, when I follow the advice I found on this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226944/pass-and-gpg-no-public-key, things don't seem to work out as they should. The command used and its output while trying to replace the original gpg key with an alternate gpg key was:
$ pass init -p .password-store GPG-id
mkdir: created directory '/home/naphelge/.password-store/.password-store'
Password store initialized for GPG-id (.password-store)
[master 8d65cea] Set GPG id to GPG-id (.password-store).
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

So the command seems to just be making a new dir, .password-store in the original dir .password-store and creating a new .gpg-id file with my new key's GPG-id in it, and not proceeding to re-encrypt all of the gpg files in .password-store with the new gpg-key.
The same advice is provided in this thread regarding a similar goal as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929307/how-to-change-the-gpg-key-of-the-pass-password-store
I noticed that in the original .gpg-id file in the ~/.password-store dir that it is the original gpg-key's fingerprint (without spaces between the (10) 4 digit blocks) that is saved. So I did try the same command above, pass init -p .password-store FINGERPRINT-id, using the new key's fingerprint (without spaces), as well trying just specifying the email address associated with the key, pass init -p .password-store naphelge@email.com, to try and initiate the re-encryption of the gpg files in .password-store with the new gpg-key, but always with the same result.
So I am not sure, looking at other posts and the pass man page what else to try to get this to work. Any suggestions or advice appreciated. Thks.

Try your command but leave off the -p   since .password-store is the default.  Also make sure you've got a backup in case it fails.

The issue can/was resolved using the GUI QTPass app. QTPass made it straightforward to add the second key, re-encrypting all files in the store with it, and then uncheck the original key.

I could find no trace of any GUI features in QTPass that would support this. Frustrating.
